# iOS app that scans Contacts for birthdays and anniversaries and provide notifications for same

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, calendar, reminders

I am looking for an App that reminds me of Birthdays and Anniversaries. If app can remind me of other dates, it would be "icing on cake" (added advantage).

I know notifications can be handled by native/default Calendar app available on any iOS device.

But catch is, App has to scan contacts and show/notify Birthdays and Anniversaries.

Default Calendar app does good job when it comes to scanning and notifying about Birthdays. But I want app to notify me both - Birthdays and Anniversaries.

I found two app from App store

1. Yearly (Paid - [link](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/yearly-birthday-anniversary/id469350106?mt=8)): I saw app screenshots, but didn't find any instance of anniversaries.
2. Anniversary Reminder (Free, Ads-Supported - [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anniversary-reminder/id614159715?mt=8)): Bad UI, also ads :(

If anyone is using Yearly, I would like to know how it handles anniversaries.

If you know any other app that does what I need, let me know via your response/reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Yearly - [link](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/yearly-birthday-anniversary/id469350106?mt=8). It's working quite well.